# The binary-GCD algorithm state machine

Tags: algorithms, proof-techniques

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Runtime of the binary-GCD state machine](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6404/runtime-of-the-binary-gcd-state-machine)

**Hello I am doing self study from MIT OCW exercises and I could not understand this question. Can anyone explain me,**

- First, why does this state machine assume it halves the $(max(a,b))$ at every two transitions beacuse we can follow steps 4 and 7 and one extra step to halve the $(max(a,b))$, which is more than 2 transitions/steps. I know it is not a common case but a case is a case unless proved.
- Next I dont see where an extra 3 comes from in $3+2log(max(a,b))$

**Question:**
The binary-GCD state machine computes the GCD of a and b using only division
by 2 and subtraction, which makes it run very efficiently on hardware that uses binary
representation of numbers. In practice, it runs more quickly than the Euclidean
algorithm state machine.

**Prove that the machine reaches a final state in at most $3+2log(max(a,b))$
transitions.**

**Hint:** Strong induction on $max(a,b)$

states: $\mathbb{N}^3$

start state: $(a,b,1)$, where $a >b>0$

transitions: if $min(x,y) >0$, then $(x,y,e) \rightarrow $

the first possible state according to rules

**1-** $(1,0,ex)$ if $(x=y)$

**2-** $(1,0,e)$ if $(y=1)$

**3-** $(x/2,y/2,2e)$ if $(2|x \ and \ 2|y)$

**4-** $(y,x,e)$ if $(y>x)$

**5-** $(x,y/2,e)$ if $(2|y)$

**6-** $(x/2,y,e)$ if $(2|x)$

**7-** $(x-y,y,e)$ if $(otherwise)$